# How can I make a label with frame using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is how I want it.

[image: Click to see the image]

I tried using the border option in the label itself but the problem is I am not using a frame so it's causing some undesired problems like if the temp or location changes so does the border. So it becomes small some times or sometimes goes out of the window

Comment: Have you tried packing the "Location:" and "Temp:" labels inside one frame, then giving that frame a border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect it into frame.
Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

#Creating frame 
frame = Frame(window,         #Connect it to window
              bg="pink",        #BaackGround color
              bd=5,  #Just border you can change that
              relief=SUNKEN)
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame,      #CONNECT IT TO THE FRAME
              text='This is label',
             )
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```